# Excel: Trying to return a value when "ACT Mastery" is found, but NOT "ACT Mastery Advanced"

Tags: excel

Here's the code I have now:

`=IF(COUNTIFS('moodle-import'!$A2:$Z2,"*"&"ACT Mastery"&"*",'moodle-import'!$A2:$Z2,"<>Advanced"),"Moodle-ACTM","N/A")`

I essentially want to return "Moodle-ACTM" when the text "ACT Mastery" is found in a cell, but NOT when "ACT Mastery Advanced" is found.

Ideas?

Thanks

Comment: Is it possible for you to add extra columns that you can hide? That would simplify the whole thing a lot.

Comment: @Gabor, I disagree that hiding columns makes things more simple

Answer (score 0):

You were close. Try changing the formula as follows:

```
=IF(COUNTIFS('moodle-import'!$A2:$Z2,"*ACT Mastery*",'moodle-import'!$A2:$Z2,"<>*ACT Mastery Advanced*")>0,"Moodle-ACTM","N/A")
```

Answer (score 0):

Alternatively you can stick with your `COUNTIFS` formula.

You were close with your original formula, you just need asterisks around the second criteria but also to include the full exclusion criteria otherwise if 'Advanced' appeared anywhere in the string it would be missed:

`=IF(COUNTIFS('moodle-import'!$A2:$Z2,"*ACT Mastery*",'moodle-import'!$A2:$Z2,"<>"&"*ACT Mastery Advanced*")>0,"Moodle-ACTM","N/A")`